# Updating target for DataGridColumn bound to DataRow through converter

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, strongly-typed-dataset

This question is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42611351/cannot-bind-to-additional-properties-on-typed-datarow

What I have done now is to use a converter to fill in the data grid column with a value that I calculate from other fields in the typed data row.  Things are working fine with initial update.  The problem comes now when I change one of the row values on which the calculated value depends.  I cannot figure out how to update the target of the calculation.

Here is the XAML...

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:FullNameConverter x:Key="FullNameConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding TableA}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}"  Width="30*" Header="Name" SortDirection="Ascending" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Width="30*" Binding="{Binding Value}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Full Name" Width="30*" 
                                Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource FullNameConverter}}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Here is the code behind...

```
public partial class BindingBench : Window
{
    SimplyDataSet _dataSet = new SimplyDataSet();
    public BindingBench()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _dataSet.TableA.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("FullName",typeof(string)));
        SimplyDataSet.TableARow arow = _dataSet.TableA.AddTableARow("Z", 0.0);
        arow = _dataSet.TableA.AddTableARow("X", 1.0);
        arow = _dataSet.TableA.AddTableARow("Y", 2.0);
        DataContext = this;
    }
    public DataTable TableA
    {
        get { return _dataSet.TableA; }
    }
}
```

Here is the converter...

```
public class FullNameConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        DataRowView rv = value as DataRowView;
        if(rv != null)
        {
            SimplyDataSet.TableARow row = rv.Row as SimplyDataSet.TableARow;
            if (row != null)
            {
                return row.Name + "=" + row.Value;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Finally here is the typed dataset...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="SimplyDataSet"  targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/SimplyDataSet.xsd" xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/SimplyDataSet.xsd" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/SimplyDataSet.xsd" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:msprop="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msprop" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:appinfo source="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdatasource">
  <DataSource DefaultConnectionIndex="0" FunctionsComponentName="QueriesTableAdapter" Modifier="AutoLayout, AnsiClass, Class, Public" SchemaSerializationMode="IncludeSchema" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdatasource">
    <Connections />
    <Tables />
    <Sources />
  </DataSource>
</xs:appinfo>
</xs:annotation>
<xs:element name="SimplyDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true" msprop:EnableTableAdapterManager="true" msprop:Generator_DataSetName="SimplyDataSet" msprop:Generator_UserDSName="SimplyDataSet">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:element name="TableA" msprop:Generator_TableClassName="TableADataTable" msprop:Generator_TableVarName="tableTableA" msprop:Generator_TablePropName="TableA" msprop:Generator_RowDeletingName="TableARowDeleting" msprop:Generator_RowChangingName="TableARowChanging" msprop:Generator_RowEvHandlerName="TableARowChangeEventHandler" msprop:Generator_RowDeletedName="TableARowDeleted" msprop:Generator_UserTableName="TableA" msprop:Generator_RowChangedName="TableARowChanged" msprop:Generator_RowEvArgName="TableARowChangeEvent" msprop:Generator_RowClassName="TableARow">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="Name" msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnName" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="Name" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="NameColumn" msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="Name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
          <xs:element name="Value" msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnValue" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="Value" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="ValueColumn" msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="Value" type="xs:double" minOccurs="0" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Notes:

1. This is a complete set of code.  The reason you don't see an implementation of TableA or AddTableARow is that there is a tool (XSD) that generates the code to implement the dataset.  I could add this generated code also, but it is voluminous even for a small dataset such as this one and is otherwise not very helpful.
2. It appears to me that the basic problem I am having with these two related problems I have submitted is that the DataGridColumn is bound to the DataRow through a DataRowView.  I am adding things to the underlying DataRow without being able to modify the behavior of the DataRowView.  It would therefore seem to me that the DataSet is fundamentally incompatible with MVVM.  However I cannot seem to find any opinions that DataSet should be avoided in favor of something else.
3. I have already tried a number of approaches to get the calculated cell to update including DataRowView.BeginEdit()/EndEdit(), implementing INotifyPropertyChanged on the DataRow, etc.
4. I can get the calculated column to update by refreshing the data source.  This is not a solution!  I can live with updating all the cells in a single row but not updating every cell.

Any ideas or advice is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with your `SimplyDataSet` class, but I would suggest binding to a `CollectionViewSource` and assigning your DataSet to the `CollectionViewSource.Source`  With a `CollectionViewSource` being a proxy, it implements INotifyPropertyChanged to properly update your UI, and maintains a connection with the underlying data source.

```
public partial class BindingBench : Window
{
    CollectionViewSource dbViewsource = new CollectionViewSource();
    SimplyDataSet _dataSet = new SimplyDataSet();
    public BindingBench()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _dataSet.TableA.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("FullName", typeof(string)));
        SimplyDataSet.TableARow arow = _dataSet.TableA.AddTableARow("Z", 0.0);
        arow = _dataSet.TableA.AddTableARow("X", 1.0);
        arow = _dataSet.TableA.AddTableARow("Y", 2.0);
        dbViewsource.Source = _dataSet  //This could possibly be _dataSet.GetDefaultView()
        DataContext = dbViewSource.View;
    }
    public DataTable TableA
    {
        get { return _dataSet.TableA; }
    }
}
```

A more in depth example can be located here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547149.aspx

Comment: Yes, I know how to bind to a CollectionViewSource.  The reason I am using a typed DataSet is that it offers so much more than a CollectionViewSource.  In particular it has a schema designer that you use to set up tables and relations.  Coding with a typed DataSet is, simply put, operating at a different abstraction level.  It is so much more efficient than slinging a bunch of ObservableCollection classes and INotifyPropertyChanged enabled objects.  So it surprises me that Microsoft seems to be abandoning the typed DataSet.  UWP does not support the DataSet.  This is a clear signal I think.

Comment: I can't disagree with your interperatation, but it still seems to me like the CollectionViewSource, in overly simplistic terms, is your 'view' of the data and your DatSet is the 'model'. and INotifyProperty is implemented on your behalf so you keep your DataSet as is (not explicitly implementing INotifyPropertyChanged as you would on a POCO class model) You're not losing any binding functionality, so I'm not sure where the rub is. I'm a little green on the subject, but that's my understanding.

Comment: A fair point.  I modified your code slightly to get it working.  The problems are the same.  I change the value and the full name column does not get updated.  I haven't looked at this in depth yet, but I think the CollectionViewSource.View will simply be another layer on top of the DataView that the table creates.  So I don't think this helps but I will look into it further.

Comment: if it's still not working i would raise the question.. does your SimplyDataSet extend DataSet properly? I'll dig up a working example using just DataSet and we can try and plug in SimplyDataSet into the equation

Comment: SimplyDataSet is a typed dataset.  Do you see the XML code above?  That is the typed dataset.  To use it do this.  Create a C# project and add a DataSet.  You will get a blank schema designer.  Now right click on the dataset and open with XML editor.  You will see XML for the empty dataset.  Paste the XML above and you will have exactly what I am using.